# How to perform arithmetic operation on Option<BalanceOf<T>>?

Tags: substrate-node-template, rust, substrate-archive

Hello all developers and community members, I am very new to Substrate and Rust.

I am creating a pallet for NFT marketplace.

for storing out the NFT details I've created a struct as mentioned below.

```
pub struct NFTStruct<T: Config> {
        pub dna: [u8; 16],   // Using 16 bytes to represent a NFT DNA
        pub price: Option<BalanceOf<T>>,
        pub gender: Gender,
        pub owner: AccountOf<T>,
        pub creator: AccountOf<T>,
        pub royalty: Option<BalanceOf<T>>,
    }
```

I have two fields here 1) `price` 2) `royalty`.

I am able to set the price of nft using `set_price function` , and royalty using `set_creator_royalty function` . upto this things are working fine.

Now I have a challenge, whenever user wants to buy NFT he can buy using `buy_nft` function which I have defined inside my pallet.

```
        // buy_nft
        #[transactional]
        #[pallet::weight(100)]
        pub fn buy_nft(
            origin: OriginFor<T>,
            nft_id: T::Hash,
            bid_price: BalanceOf<T>
        ) -> DispatchResult {
            let buyer = ensure_signed(origin)?;
    
            // Check the nft exists and buyer is not the current nft owner
            let nft = Self::nfts(&nft_id).ok_or(<Error<T>>::NFTNotExist)?;
            ensure!(nft.owner != buyer, <Error<T>>::BuyerIsNFTOwner);
            
            //Check if the nft is for sale.
            // Check the nft is for sale and the nft ask price <= bid_price
            if let Some(ask_price) = nft.price {
                ensure!(ask_price <= bid_price, <Error<T>>::NFTBidPriceTooLow);
            } else {
                Err(<Error<T>>::NFTNotForSale)?;
            }
            // Check the buyer has enough free balance
            ensure!(T::Currency::free_balance(&buyer) >= bid_price, <Error<T>>::NotEnoughBalance);

            // Verify the buyer has the capacity to receive one more nft
            let to_owned = <NFTsOwned<T>>::get(&buyer);
            ensure!((to_owned.len() as u32) < T::MaxNFTsOwned::get(), <Error<T>>::ExceedMaxNFTOwned);
            let seller = nft.owner.clone();
        
            //Transfer the amount from buyer to seller
            T::Currency::transfer(&buyer, &seller, bid_price, ExistenceRequirement::KeepAlive)?;
            // Transfer the nft from seller to buyer
            Self::transfer_nft_to(&nft_id, &buyer)?;

            // Deposit relevant Event
            Self::deposit_event(Event::Bought(buyer, seller, nft_id, bid_price));
    
            Ok(())
        }
```

but in this function I want to make changes for `royalty_split` , I mean, whenever user tends to buy NFT at the price which owner has set and the royalty in percent which creator set using `set_creator_royalty function`  should be spitted from the actual price and should be transferred to creator's address and the rest should be transferred to the owner's address.

For ex-

nft with hash 0x11c5g5 has the price of 100 and the royalty is 10%. user came to buy_nft, he made a payment of 100 Tokens, 90 Tokens should be transferred to owner's wallet and 10 Tokens should be transferred to creator's wallet.

**Approaches I tried**

1

Inside the buy_nft function, I tried multiplying  nft.price and nft.royalty both are of same type Option<BalanceOf>. And divide it with 100 to get the percentages/share of creator

```
            let nft_price = nft.price;
            let creator_royalty = nft.royalty;
            let creator_share_percent = nft_price * creator_royalty /100;
```

**I got this errror**

```
cannot multiply `std::option::Option<<<T as pallet::Config>::Currency as frame_support::traits::Currency<<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId>>::Balance>` by `std::option::Option<<<T as pallet::Config>::Currency as frame_support::traits::Currency<<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId>>::Balance>`
```

2

I have tried to solve it with different approaches as well, I thought I should convert/typecast both of these values to U64 (Rust primitive type).

For it I used a function

```
        //function to  convert balance to u64
        pub fn balance_to_u64(input: BalanceOf<T>) -> Option<u64> {
            TryInto::<u64>::try_into(input).ok()
        }
```

But the issue is, the function `balance_to_u64`  only takes `BalanceOf<T>>` as an argument and my type is `Option<BalanceOf<T>>`.

If I try to pass `nft.price` or `nft.royalty` as a parameter inside `balance_to_u64` function I got this error.

```
mismatched types

expected associated type, found enum `std::option::Option`

note: expected associated type `<<T as pallet::Config>::Currency as frame_support::traits::Currency<<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId>>::Balance`
                    found enum `std::option::Option<<<T as pallet::Config>::Currency as frame_support::traits::Currency<<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId>>::Balance>`
help: consider constraining the associated type `<<T as pallet::Config>::Currency as frame_support::traits::Currency<<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId>>::Balance` to `std::option::Option<<<T as pallet::Config>::Currency as frame_support::traits::Currency<<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId>>::Balance>`
note: for more information, visit https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html
```

I have spent around 1 week to solve this problem but unfortunately I got no solution. I am totally frustrated and looking for some help from any of the senior person.

If you have any solution or any suggestion for me, please help me out.

Thank you

Comment: Hi, could I ask why you're using an option for the royalties? Does this mean that the royalties might not be set on nfts? Wouldn't it be better to either have a fixed or default to zero? That way you can avoid the whole option situation

Comment: Hi Yes depends on creator weather he wants to set royalty for his NFT or not, that's why I used Option here. I don't know if there is any better approach to solve this problem. As I am very new to Substrate. 

Thank you for your  response.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
let creator_share_percent = nft.royalty.map(|creator_roality| {
    nft.price.unwrap_or_default() * creator_roality /100
});
```

But be aware that `creator_share_percent` is again an `Option`. So, you need to handle it as `Option` as well. You will then probably do something like:

```
if let Some(creator_share_percent) = creator_share_percent {
    // pay the creator share.
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response,

But I am still facing errors.

Comment: mismatched types

expected associated type, found integer

note: expected associated type `<<T as pallet::Config>::Currency as frame_support::traits::Currency<<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId>>::Balance`
                    found type `{integer}`
help: consider constraining the associated type `<<T as pallet::Config>::Currency as frame_support::traits::Currency<<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId>>::Balance` to `{integer}`
note: for more information, visit https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html

Comment: This is the error I got as I used your code.

0


let creator_share_percent = nft.royalty.map(|creator_roality| {
    nft.price.unwrap_or_default() * creator_roality /100
});

Comment: I think it's due the the number 100 which we are dividing.

Comment: Ahh yeah sorry, just write `100u32.into()`.

Comment: Hey, things are working fine now. Thank you for helping me out.